# Windows Server Program Restrictions for Administrator?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, group-policy

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 OS where I just created a standard user account. I went into the Local Group Policy Editor and [set the OS to only allow certain programs to be run](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8739/restrict-users-to-run-only-specified-programs-in-windows-7/). I figured that this change would apply to non-administrative accounts, but now my administrator account is locked out from opening any programs.

I cannot open the policy editor to revert this change, even if I right click > Run as Administrator. Any ideas on how to rollback this change?

Comment: Is that a member of a domain, or a standalone system.  You should be able to remotely manage it using RSAT tools from a Windows 7 workstation or another 2008r2 system.

Comment: @Zoredache It's a standalone system

Comment: Restore from backups or use a boot disk/repair console to manually remove that group policy setting.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Yep, that's what I'm looking into doing. Just getting my repair disk together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really saved my server, try option 3: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/214461-local-group-policy-reset-default.html

Note, this option will **RESET ALL LOCAL GROUP POLICY** options. Use with caution and at your own risk. First, you need to boot into a recovery disk and start up the recovery command prompt.
Recreated here:

---

To Reset "Local Group Policy" to Default in a Command Prompt at Boot

1. Open a command prompt at boot in Vista or Windows 7 or Windows 8. NOTE: See OPTION ONE at this link for how if needed.
2. In the command prompt, type diskpart, and press Enter. (see screenshot)
3. In the command prompt, type list volume, and press Enter. (see screenshot)
4. Make note of what your Windows OS drive letter is. It is not always C: at boot. (see screenshot) NOTE: Mine just happens to be D: at boot.
5. In the command prompt, type exit, and press Enter. (see screenshot)
6. In the command prompt, type the command below, and press Enter. (see screenshot) NOTE: Substitute D in the command below with your drive letter from step 4 instead.

   ```
   RD /S /Q "D:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy"
   ```
7. In the command prompt, type the command below, and press Enter. (see screenshot) NOTE: Substitute D in the command below with your drive letter from step 4 instead.

   ```
   RD /S /Q "D:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers"
   ```
8. Restart the computer back into Windows.
9. The Local Group Policy Editor has now been reset back to default.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use the following command to edit Local Security Policy of a remote computer. You could also overwrite the local policy with Group Policy if you are joined to a Domain.

gpedit.msc /gpcomputer:"target"

Since, the computer is not joined to a Domain. Boot the server into Safe Mode and change the policy.

Comment: Safe mode does not affect this policy.